# Flexbox Sizing Question - Body is Overflowing 100VH

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on styling an app.

I want the app to have 2 components to it which should vertically flex within the body. The first is a navbar at the top. The second is the rest of my page, `.wholePage`.

`.wholePage` itself is a flexbox that should vertically flex two more items, `.topHalf` and `.bottomHalf`.

`.topHalf` should be a flexbox that horizontally flexes two components.

`.bottomHalf` should take up the remainder of the viewport, and scroll if there is too much content.

However, two things are unexpectedly happening. The first is that when I add the CSS selector:

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

My page no longer fits within the viewport, even though I have defined the body to have `height: 100vh;`, why is this?

Secondly, when I add content inside `.topRightHalf`, such as `<p>hello</p>`, the flexbox vertically grows! I do not know why this is as both my `.topHalf` and `.bottomHalf` have `flex: 1;` set, so I thought they should share the height of their parent.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wholePage {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topHalf {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.topLeftHalf {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  flex: 1;
}

.topRightHalf {
  border: 1px dotted brown;
  flex: 1;
}

.bottomHalf {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Solve</a></li>
  <li><a>About</a></li>
  <li><a>Other</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="wholePage">

  <div class="topHalf">
    <div class="topLeftHalf">
      This is the top left half
    </div>
    <div class="topRightHalf">
      This is the top right half
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottomHalf">
    <p>I can scroll</p>
    <p>I can scroll</p>
    <p>I can scroll</p>
    <p>I can scroll</p>
    <p>I can scroll</p>
    <p>I can scroll</p>
    <p>I can scroll</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

My code is below, I have also included a codepen link: https://codepen.io/Sean713/pen/NWzovQO?editors=1100

Comment: Your codepen link is not working.

Comment: My mistake, I pasted the wrong link- I will edit it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an overflow. The horizontal scrollbar is visible because of:

```css
.bottomHalf {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

`overflow: scroll` always shows the scrollbar even if there's no overflow. You should use `overflow-y` instead to only show the vertical scrollbar.

I also recommend you to use grid instead of flex:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto auto;
}

nav, 
#BottomHalf {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#TopLeftHalf {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

#TopRightHalf {
  border: 1px dotted brown;
}

#BottomHalf {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <menu>
    <li><a>Solve</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Other</a></li>
  </menu>
</nav>

<!--Top Half-->
<section id="TopLeftHalf">This is the top left half</section>
<section id="TopRightHalf">This is the top right half</section>

<!--Bottom Half-->
<section id="BottomHalf">
  <p>I can scroll</p>
  <p>I can scroll</p>
  <p>I can scroll</p>
  <p>I can scroll</p>
  <p>I can scroll</p>
  <p>I can scroll</p>
  <p>I can scroll</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Chiroika, thank you for your response.

I think I was able to get it mostly working with flexbox (I will try using a grid next for practice), I have a new codepen here: https://codepen.io/Sean713/pen/VwdgMEx?editors=1100

My only issue is when the green div has too much content (if you uncomment the p tags), it makes all the divs bigger! How can I contain those p tags within the green div and prevent it from expanding the divs?